# Removing Paginated URLs From jekyll-sitemap

Tags: pagination, jekyll, static-site, static-site-generation, jekyll-paginator

How to Remove Paginated URLs From Jekyll-sitemap ⬇
[image: example sitemap file content]

```
pagination:
  enabled: true
  per_page: 6
  offset: 0
  permalink: "/page/:num/"
  title: ":title - page :num of :max"
  limit: 0
  sort_field: date
  sort_reverse: true
```

I am using pagination v2,

I tried

```
paginate_path: "/blog/page/:num/"

defaults:
- scope:
    path: "blog/page"
  values:
    sitemap: false
```

and

```
paginate_path: "/blog/:num/"
defaults:
- scope:
    path: "blog"
  values:
    sitemap: false
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

As I tried all possible solutions getting from research but nothing works in my case so I suggest adding

> **sitemap: false**

in the front matter of your

> /blog/

page, this will remove all the pages generated by the paginator but this will also remove /blog/ URL so, for this, you have to make a new .md file with only

> permalink: "/blog/"

and redirect this link to your main blog page such as

[image]

it may help you